# Encryption of VHD used to boot

Tags: encryption, boot, vhd

Can boot to VHD file be encrypted and still boot under Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

Not according to [requently Asked Questions: Virtual Hard Disks in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440865(WS.10).aspx#two)

> What is not supported for native boot when using VHDs?
>
> Using compressed or encrypted VHDs for native boot. VHDs that have been compressed by NTFS or encrypted using Encrypting File System on the host volume are not supported for native boot.